# Can we publish a chrome extension with only native messaging feature included?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store, chrome-native-messaging

I created an extension that can communicate with my native C # application using Google Chrome native messaging.

However, Google's Chrome Webstore policy [states](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/program_policies#spam):

> Do not post an app where the primary functionality is to install or launch another app, theme, or extension. For example, if your app’s primary function is to launch a desktop app that the user has already installed, that is not allowed. Another example is a Chrome App that just launches a website.

So, how can I use native messaging and publish my extension on the webstore?

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't publicate an extension that has only the functionality of installing or launching some other application. Yours serve to communicate between the application and the browser. I don't think you'll have any trouble.

Comment: My extension is to read a barcode with a webcam using opencv and get the result to fill an input field.

Comment: If so, you're not violating any terms. You're able to use external programs on your extension. You just shouldn't install that external program trough the extension.

Comment: Hello Phiter thanks for your answer, my extension was rejected because I've forgot to fill the owner property of the subdomain attached to the extension, this is not related to the communication between my application and the extension. All is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Finally my extension has been accepted on the webstore with the only use of native messaging so yes we can publish an extension with only this feature and this is not a cause of reject, my issue came from the fact that i forgot to validate my website for the extension .